# Optimal Hardware for > 30K Requests / min?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, memory, mysql-5.7

We have some performance issues with one of our Test-Machines a MySQL 5.7.21 Standalone Server.

We have: 8 CPUs 16GB RAM (`buffer_pool_size` 5.6 G) and need to handle > 30 K Requests / minute.

When we run our tests the CPU workload raised to 100% and we got several issues (long query run time etc...)

What is your hardware recommendation for this workload?
ty in advance br Andreas

Comment: How long is a piece of string? You hit a cpu limit but where else is the server hurting? RAM? I/O? Can you modify the code? Is the query just naturally cpu intensive?

Comment: Is that single thread/connection? Whats the transction time for lower query volumes? How much does each query change? How big are the tables its hitting is it all cached in memory? Is it only querying data or is it inserting and updating too?

Comment: Depending on all of the above the answer might be more CPU, more RAM , faster disk, different drive layouts, indexing or even table schema design.

Comment: @aeaeae  
Additional information request, please post in original question (or on pastebin.com). 
current complete my.cnf-ini 
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
gathered just after your TEST has finished for basic tuning suggestions, you will probably be amazed.

Comment: @aeaeae  Any chance the requested information can be added to the Question with EDIT?  If not, MODERATOR, please REMOVE the entire question, there is not much useful information in the Question.

Answer (score 2):

500 inserts per second is definitely into the area where out-of-the-box MySQL begins to have trouble.

Some things to do:

- Don't trust benchmarks; use your code.
- Combine one-row `INSERTs` into transactions.  (Much of what is limiting you to 500qps is the transaction overhead.
- "Batch" inserts -- 100-1000 rows per `INSERT` statement gives you 10x performance improvement.
- Use `LOAD DATA` -- also 10x (maybe more).
- Switch to SSDs -- perhaps 10x faster than spinning drives.
- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2` -- much faster, but less secure in a crash.
- Decrease the number of indexes, *especially `UNIQUE`*, on the table.
- Do not use UUIDs.
- Gather data some other way (eg, MyISAM table with no indexes), then batch `INSERT...SELECT...`.  This has the added advantage of giving you a change to efficiently do ETL transformations.
- My [*High Speed Ingestion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) technique.  It involves ping-ponging between two staging tables and handles various variations (multiple connections, etc)